# arch linux update warnings missing firmwares

Tags: arch-linux, pacman

I am using the latest Arch Linux as my main machine.
I update it daily using  `sudo pacman -Syu` and it gives these warnings:

[image]

It doesn't break, or anything, but can someone explain those warnings and how to solve them?

Comment: Please [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/22222). Instead, copy/paste the text into your question and use the [formatting tools](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to format it as code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
==> WARNING: Possibly missing firmware for module: qla2xxx
==> WARNING: Possibly missing firmware for module: qla1280
==> WARNING: Possibly missing firmware for module: wd719x
==> WARNING: Possibly missing firmware for module: aic94xx
==> WARNING: Possibly missing firmware for module: qed
==> WARNING: Possibly missing firmware for module: bfa
==> WARNING: Possibly missing firmware for module: xhci_pci
```

If your system includes hardware that needs any of those modules, install the necessary firmware. You can do that either by installing your distribution's appropriate firmware package(s), or by directly downloading the necessary firmware files from [linux-firmware Git repository](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/tree/) and placing them under `/lib/firmware` on your system.

If you don't have the hardware that needs the module mentioned in a warning message, you can ignore the warning. (If you don't need a particular module, you could adjust your kernel configuration to not build that module at all, to get rid of the message.)

Answer (score 0):

Check the Arch Wiki about these warnings here:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Mkinitcpio#Possibly_missing_firmware_for_module_XXXX